# Sort dbReadtable using wday in R

Tags: mysql, r, lubridate

I have a dbReadtable which I wanna sort by week date. My table looks as follow:

```
Id Date       Number
1  2020-11-01 1
2  2020-11-03 3
3  2020-11-02 4
4  2020-11-01 2
5  2020-11-02 4
6  2020-11-03 3
7  2020-11-06 7
8  2020-11-05 4
9  2020-11-08 2
```

I want the output to look something like this:

```
Day       Number
 
Sunday    5
Monday    8
Tuseday   6
Thursday  4
Friday    7
```

For this, I wanna use $wday in lubridate library.

My code looks as follow:

```
data <- dbReadTable(con, "observations")
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table` and `lubridate` and assuming Date is already a date (not a string).

```
library(lubridate)
library(data.table)

data <- dbReadTable(con, "observations")

data[, by=.(Day=wday(Date, label=TRUE, abbr=FALSE, locale="C")), .(Number=sum(Number))]

#        Day Number
#1:   Sunday      5
#2:  Tuesday      6
#3:   Monday      8
#4:   Friday      7
#5: Thursday      4
```

I added locale to return english names for days (I'm french and get french names :-).